# Join two tables and group by problems

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Problems

`id | name`

Responses

`id | problem_id | user_id | value`

I have the following statement.

```
SELECT 
`problems`.name, 
problem_id, 
sum(value) as knowledge, 
COUNT(*) as attempts FROM `responses`
LEFT JOIN `problems` ON `problems`.id = `responses`.problem_id
WHERE problem_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id = 4
GROUP BY problem_id
```

It produces a list like so:

```
| name      | problem_id | knowledge | attempts |
| NULL      | 1          | 6         | 6        |
| NULL      | 2          | 5         | 6        |
| NULL      | 3          | 4         | 6        |
| NULL      | 4          | 3         | 5        |
```

I'm missing something and I would be grateful if someone could help format to:

```
| name      | problem_id | knowledge | attempts |
| Problem A | 1          | 6         | 6        |
| Problem B | 2          | 5         | 6        |
| Problem C | 3          | 4         | 6        |
| Problem D | 4          | 3         | 5        |
```

Comment: Please stop using `GROUP BY` in this fashion. It is not ANSI standard.

Comment: How can I orient myself to ANSI standards?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: DON'T DO THAT. Completely unecessary. You'd just be playing into someone's OCD

Comment: Okay. I **rm -rf /**'d my system! Now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
select p.`name`, p.`id`, r.`user_id`, sum(r.`value`) as knowledge
from
`responses` r
join `problems` p on r.`problem_id` = p.`id`
where
r.`user_id` = 4
group by p.`name`, p.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have in your SELECT something that is neither an aggregate function (like SUM or AVG), nor a variable part of the GROUP BY.

In your case, the name is neither.

Some DBMS might let you do it (MySQL), but the result is unpredictable.

Solution:

```
SELECT 
`problems`.name, 
problem_id, 
sum(value) as knowledge, 
COUNT(*) as attempts FROM `responses`
LEFT JOIN `problems` ON `problems`.id = `responses`.problem_id
WHERE problem_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id = 4
GROUP BY problem_id, problems.name
```

Comment: This is a comment really - although, to be fair, there isn't really a question.

Comment: LOL you are right, re-reading the question I realized it too.

Comment: What's the solution then?